# How to get AES token using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, aes

I followed the step in the Azure Doc(Using AES-128 Dynamic Encryption and Key Delivery Service) and published a video by using the .NET SDK. 
When I request a sample token using azure media explorer, and using that token
i am able to play the encrypted video.

If I request a token using .NET SDK, the token received is invalid and the video doesn't play.

Comment: Would you post your token? You'll need to add bearer before your token when you pass it to a player.

Comment: It worked. Thanks